# Debian Server Upload-Limit via PHP and SFTP

Tags: php, apache, ftp, debian

do you know where upload limits can be set on a debian server running apache2 and php7 outside of php?

Problem: Can't upload files bigger than ~2MB

Tried solutions: configuring php.ini (both apache2 and cli) for 10M upload, including `post_max_size` `memory_limit` `upload_max_filesize` `file_uploads`.
`LimitRequestBody` in htaccess currently undefinined.

Also the problem also effects uploads via SFTP - so it shouldnt be a PHP issue.
What configuration am I missing?

Comment: Try ask at https://serverfault.com/

Comment: What framework or CMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Actually these settings should be in `php.ini`. After editing don't forget to restart your Apache.

Indeed there could be some other files, which contain these settings. Read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381522/php-7-php-ini-upload-max-filesize-not-working).